# Universal Snackbar accessible in the entire React application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, snackbar

I've been playing with MUI React library and found [Snackbar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/).

[image]

I found it a nice idea for displaying feedback information for a user.
In my app I'd like use it to display results of sending a request to server (e.g. "data sent successfully", etc).

I used the code defined [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#system-CustomizedSnackbars.tsx), but I quickly realized that in order to display messages dynamically I need to store message text, `isOpen` boolean and message type (`success`, `error`, etc.) with `useState` and then set it before showing a message, e.g.

```js
    const sendData = () => {
        fetch({
            // ...
        })
        .then(() => {
            setMessage("Success!");
            setLevel("success");
            setOpen(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setMessage("Failed to send request.");
            setLevel("error");
            setOpen(true);
        });
    }
```

1.) This is inconvenient. I wonder if there's a way to use it in a simpler way, like this:

```js
    const sendData = () => {
        fetch({
            // ...
        })
        .then(() => {
            showMessage("Success!", "success");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setMessage("Failed to send request.", "error");
        });
    }
```

2.) The `Snackbar` component defined like this is local to its parent component. I wonder if it's possible to make it reusable and share it throughout my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, We need to create a lot of unnecessary states to show `Snackbar`. You can use an alternative and simple solution to this. It is a library built on top of MUI Snackbar. As you check at [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#complementary-projects), MUI adds it to complementary projects on the Snackbar documentation page.

It is a very easy-to-use and highly customizable `Snackbar hook`. You add `<SnackbarProvider/>` once on the top level of your app and then you can access it anywhere using `useSnackbar()` hook.

You can find more examples and docs on their [official page](https://notistack.com/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, this looks exactly like something I had in mind, thanks. I'll give it a go after work and will post my thoughts here.